# Add Multiple Widgets to GWT flextable

Tags: gwt, flextable

is there a way to do this? I am trying to add a textbox and a button within one cell in a flextable.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just wrap them in a FlowPanel or another panel.

Something like

```
Widget widget1 = new Label("Hello");
Widget widget2 = new Label("World");
FlowPanel panel = new FlowPanel();
panel.add(widget1);
panel.add(widget2);
// get the table
table.setWidget(x, y, panel);
```

Comment: awesome works perfectly thanks. ill check your answer in 2 minutes when i can